# Как отследить что время стало равно текущему?

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть проект на Ангуляре 8, есть напоминалки, которые пользователь может создавать на будущее, смысл в том что надо пользователя уведомить о напоминании когда текущее время равно времени, которое поставилось в напоминании.
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Сравниваете время в напоминалке и текущее. Каков вопрос, таков и ответ :)

Comment: Можете на сервере хранить дату в виде строки по типу "2020-05-07 21:00". А потом на стороне клиента каждую минуту с самому либо с помощью либы https://momentjs.com/ генерировать строку в таком же формате и сравнивать с датами напоминаний, если совпали, то выводить его

Answer (score 0):

1. Хранить дату оповещения.
2. Когда пользователь заходит на сайт создавать таймер на разницу между датой оповещения и текущей с необходимым колбеком.

В данном случае ответственность за то чтобы оповещение сработало без опозданий будет лежать на WebAPI. В результате вы не будете загружать процессорное время лишними проверками.